Plotting the result of NDSolve for different values of a parameter
I have numerically solved an integral and plotted the result for a specific value $ll=0.1$ in a function g.
    g[ll_, b_] := (1 - E^(-b  ll))/ll;
num = 30;
numb = num + 1;
xy12 = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];
xy12b = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];


For[i = 1, i < numb, i++,
 sf = (i - 1)/10;
 lsty = ParallelTable[{S0, 
    Cos[NIntegrate[g[0.1, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0, 0, sf, 0.2}];
 lstx = ParallelTable[{S0, -Sin[
      NIntegrate[g[0.1, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0, 0, sf, 0.2}];
 fx = Interpolation[lstx, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
 fy = Interpolation[lsty, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
 xy12[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
 xy12b[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
 xy12[[i, 2]] = NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];
 xy12b[[i, 2]] = -NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];]
p12 = ListPlot[xy12, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-4, 4}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];
p12b = ListPlot[xy12b, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-4, 4}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];

Show[{
  p12, p12b}]

Now I want to do the same for different values of $ll$ and plot the graphs in different colors. But I get an error when I try to do that. Here is my attempt.
    g[ll_, b_] := (1 - E^(-b  ll))/ll;
num = 30;
numc = 3;
numb = num + 1;
xy12 = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];
xy12b = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];

For[j = 1, j < numc, j++,
 For[i = 1, i < numb, i++,
    sf = (i - 1)/10;
    lsty = 
     ParallelTable[{S0, Cos[NIntegrate[g[j/10, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0,
        0, sf, 0.2}];
    lstx = 
     ParallelTable[{S0, -Sin[
         NIntegrate[g[j/10, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0, 0, sf, 0.2}];
    fx = Interpolation[lstx, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
    fy = Interpolation[lsty, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
    xy12[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
    xy12b[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
    xy12[[i, 2]] = NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];
    xy12b[[i, 2]] = -NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];]
   p12[j] = 
  ListPlot[xy12, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];
 p12b[j] = 
  ListPlot[xy12b, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];
 ]

Show[{
  p12[1], p12b[1],p12[2], p12b[2],p12[3], p12b[3]}]

Could someone please help me with this?

There are several typos in your code. After cleanup we have
g[ll_, b_] := (1 - E^(-b   ll))/ll;
num = 30;
numc = 3;
numb = num + 1;
xy12 = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];
xy12b = RandomInteger[num, {num, 2}];

For[j = 1, j <= numc, j++, For[i = 1, i < numb, i++, sf = (i)/10;
  lsty = 
   ParallelTable[{S0, Cos[NIntegrate[g[j/10, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0, 
     0, sf, 0.2  sf}];
  lstx = 
   ParallelTable[{S0, -Sin[NIntegrate[g[j/10, s], {s, 0, S0}]]}, {S0, 
     0, sf, 0.2  sf}];
  fx = Interpolation[lstx, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
  fy = Interpolation[lsty, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
  xy12[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
  xy12b[[i, 1]] = NIntegrate[fx[x], {x, 0, sf}];
  xy12[[i, 2]] = NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];
  xy12b[[i, 2]] = -NIntegrate[fy[x], {x, 0, sf}];];
 p12[j] = 
  ListPlot[xy12, PlotRange -> {{-3, .5}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[j/4], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];
 p12b[j] = 
  ListPlot[xy12b, PlotRange -> {{-3, .5}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[j/7], Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}, Ticks -> None];
 ]

Visualization
{p12[1], p12b[1], p12[2], p12b[2], p12[3], p12b[3]}


 Show[p12[1], p12b[1], p12[2], p12b[2], p12[3], p12b[3]]


